# What is XPath Expressions to extract this data?

Tags: testing, xpath, jmeter

ORDER_ID (next line)
1209314

what will be the XPath expression to fetch only the 2nd line that is the order id, it is in string format and got this data from a JDBC request. The sql query was -- select order_id from sub where value="abc"

Tried ways like
//OrderNumber/text()
//Order_id/text()

Comment: Without seeing the actual XML it's hard to suggest an appropriate xpath expression.

Comment: Hi, this is the result of a SQL query.

Comment: where is your [mcve] including the XML?   xpath is for XML, not a SQL query. you need to show the relevant data, or nobody can help you,

Answer (score 1):

1. XPath Extractor is for XML data.
2. You don't need to extract anything from the JDBC Request, given you properly configure it JMeter should save the result into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) itself. If you specify a "Variable Name" in the JDBC Request sampler, for example `ORDER_ID` JMeter will create the following variables:

   ```
   ORDER_ID_1=value from first row
   ORDER_ID_2=value from second row
   ...
   ORDER_ID_#=number of rows returned by the query
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter)